# Aspose.Words C# : How to add at the start of new page a paragraph

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I am using the C# version of the Aspose.Words library (in this case the evaluation, since I have to understand if it is good for my project).

Here is the thing:
I am using the reporting part to generate a dynamic word, and it works.

After that, I open the built report in a new Document and then I have to add a new paragraph at the start of a new page.

Here is what I do:

```
        Document finalDoc = new Document(@"C:\Words\reportFinal.docx");

        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(finalDoc);

        builder.MoveToDocumentEnd();
        builder.InsertBreak(BreakType.PageBreak);
        // Specify font formatting
        Font font = builder.Font;
        font.Size = 16;
        font.Bold = true;
        font.Name = "Arial";
        font.Underline = Underline.Dash;

        // Specify paragraph formatting
        ParagraphFormat paragraphFormat = builder.ParagraphFormat;
        paragraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = 8;
        paragraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Justify;
        paragraphFormat.KeepTogether = true;

        builder.Writeln("A whole paragraph.");
```

and it works, except I have a page break with a blank page, and then a new page with my paragraph.

I should need to make a page break and then write them at the start of the new page the paragraph.

Then I tried to do it without the page break, but there was a problem the library put some new lines before my paragraph.

What should I do?